# Image overlay on profile Picture FB or adding Frame to Picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Want to make a tool to add any Image overlay on profile Picture FB. I am looking in to few post regarding this. I am new to it. Is there any FB api for the same. Or it needs to be designed separately. Please if any one can help me out.

Actually I want to add a frame to the profile picture of the user logged in on single link or button clicked.

Comment: Can you elaborate at all?

Comment: Actually I want to add a frame to the profile picture of the user logged in on single link or button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Facebook's [Profile Expression Kit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit) at all? There is a [section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios#uploading) on uploading profile pictures and videos.

**EDIT:**
Graph API has [User Picture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/) to get a profile picture. Make your own edits to the picture (add the frame) and then use upload API.

Comment: I have gone through the same. But what I want is to make a link or something that user click and a Frame made by me is added there profile pic.